# Real world example for loop back address

Tags: networking, ip

What can we get as a real world example to understand loop back address?
As example broadcasting can be explain using radio stations and multi-casting  as video conference and uni-casting as normal telephone call . So what is the real world example for loop back address?

Comment: Actually, you don't have the broadcast and multicast right. Multicast is more like a commercial radio or television station; only those who tune in get the data. In a broadcast, every host _must_ interrupt and inspect the data to see if it applies to them. Multicasts only interrupt the hosts which subscribe to the multicast group. A video conference, or conference call, is a two-way conversation, but multicasts are one-way.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks. Do you have  any idea about loop back?

Comment: A loopback address is like a boomerang. If you send anything to it, it comes right back to you. It doesn't get sent anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Without loopback interface you cannot connect with any application to any other application on your local machine.